# picture gallery says "The requested content cannot be loaded.” (fancybox)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, themes, fancybox, buddypress

i'm having a problem with my new buddypress-theme (buddyboss). theres a picture-gallery in it which worked fine when i installed it. it even works fine with the same theme-files on my local installation. but now it says "The requested content cannot be loaded.” when i click on a thumbnail to open it. thats weird because it worked well in the beginning. i can't tell what i did wrong... heres the page: http://crowdartgallery.de/members/superduper/pictures/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looking at this page:

http://crowdartgallery.de/activity/p/22/?buddyboss_ajax_pic=true

which is returning a 404. You need to have it request the actual url of the image.

Using Chrome's dev tools you can view the web requests and see what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks i did the trick.. it was an inside conflict of the theme... thanks fpr your quick answer!

Comment: Glad you solved it. I couldn't say how the html was being generated but it was definitely linking to a 404 :)